# Adding text and radio inputs to alert controller ionic

Tags: html, ionic-framework

I’m looking to create a pop up where by the user inputs data, then select one of two radio options by the UI seems to screw up when I have a combination of both text type and radio type in a pop-up.
Here is my code:
[image]

Comment: please provide snipet or jsfidler

Comment: Adam Goldberg ,DO you get any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I was also looking for same thing today.
But look at [this discussion](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/feat-is-there-a-feature-to-mix-checkbox-inputs-and-radio-in-alert/45836), which says mixing of `radio`, `checkbox` or `text box` is not available right now.

I also tried to add mixture of `radio` and `text field` in alert. But styling never appeared correct.

I am moving on to implement this feature using a `ionic page` so that I can use [Ionic Modal](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/modal/ModalController/). This behaves as a modal window on large screen and as pushed page in smaller screen.

I needed to send back data from parent page to child page and other way too. Thus Ionic Modal suited best for this in my situation which can be used on `component/page`.

Refert to this [detailed usage instructions](https://alligator.io/ionic/modals/) for Ionic Modal.

Same feature has been requested from [Ionic team](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/5724).

Comment: When you say ionic page... what do you mean by that?

Comment: @AdamGoldberg, By `Ionic Page` I just meant normal Ionic page(just like Home/Main page) which we generally create using `ionic generate page myPage`. See this [Ionic CLI](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/generate/). I have updated my answer to explain about `Ionic Modal` which I am using currently. It doesn't gives exact feature like `alert`, but it does similar task without limitation.